# Moving from Hibernate Criteria to JPA is so confusing. How do I change this code to JPA and use disjunction() with the JPA code below

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, migration

```java
Criteria someTypeCrit = detCrit.createCriteria("someType","st");
Criteria myCrit = someTypeCrit.createCriteria("theme");

// And how do I use disjunction() with this JPA code. 

someSelection.where(builder.disjunction().where(builder.lessThan(root.get(Idea.PERIOD_OF_PERFORMANCE_END), new Date())
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to find out is to just get the JPQL query string after it's been compiled, using some typecasting.

```
Query<Obj> query = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery, Obj.class);
String jpql = ((org.hibernate.query.Query) query).getQueryString();
logger.info("Compiled query #31: {}", jpql);
```

If your Hibernate version is older, your typecast would be to `org.hibernate.Query`